# How to validate a input-field with JavaScript no matter which date format it is?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, ecmascript-6

I have an input field. A locale argument is defined in the beginning (like `'ch-de'`). I want to validate the input on the basis of the locale argument.
For example when the locale is `'en-uk'` then the date has to be like `7/25/2018` but when the locale is `'de-ch'` is has to be `25.7.2018`.

In addition it should be possible to write `7/5/2018`, `07/05/2018`, `07/5/2018` or `7/05/2018` for every format.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript parse date from toLocaleDateString for known locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832938/javascript-parse-date-from-tolocaledatestring-for-known-locale)

Answer (score 0):

I made this solution:

```
export const isDateValid = (locale = 'en-uk', inputValue = '') => {
  const date = new Date(inputValue);
  let objDate = '';
  const numeric = 'numeric';
  const twoDigit = '2-digit';
  const selectors = [numeric, twoDigit];
  const filters = ['year', 'month', 'day'];
  let options = {};
  let valid = false;

  filters.forEach((filter) => {
    options[filter] = '';
  });

  const combinations = [];
  selectors.forEach((el1) => {
    selectors.forEach((el2) => {
      options = ({
        year: selectors[0],
        month: el1,
        day: el2,
      });
      combinations.push(options);
    });
  });

  combinations.forEach((option) => {
    objDate = date.toLocaleString(locale, option);
    console.log(objDate, inputValue);
    if (objDate === inputValue && date.getFullYear().toString().length === 4) {
      console.log('richtig!!!!!');
      valid = true;
    }
  });
  return valid;
};
```